# Error Exception Array to String Conversion in Curl

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to to Integrate Hubtel Payment Gateway but getting Array to string Conversion Error Exception .

if i do CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>http_build_query ($invoice), im getting blank response

please help

```
  $items = ["name" => "Harry Potter", "quantity" => 1, "unitPrice" => 50];
      $invoice = array("items" => $items, "totalAmount" => 1, "description" => "test", "callbackUrl" => "https://localhost:8000/status","returnUrl"=>"https://localhost:8000/return","cancellationUrl"=>"https://localhost:8000/cancel",
        "merchantBusinessLogoUrl"=>"https://localhost:8000/wallet","merchantAccountNumber"=>"HM0409180006","clientReference"=> '1');
      $curl = curl_init();

      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.hubtel.com/v2/pos/onlinecheckout/items/initiate",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $invoice,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "Authorization: Basic bjJXS0o1Qjo0saMWU4NzA4ZS0wODVkLTQ0NDwUtOTQ3ZS1hZjBiODlkNzI1OWY=",
          "Content-Type: application/json",
          "Postman-Token: 2bd373c8-3669-4f5f-93e9-d3001af0a9cff",
          "cache-control: no-cache"
        ),
      ));
```

Comment: If you use `POST` method - add `CURLOPT_POST` option.

Comment: I removed the Laravel tag (It's in peer review), this has nothing to do with Laravel.
It's just plain PHP. If you want to use Laravels function use the Guzzle classes.

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
      try {
            $this->response = $this->client->request($method, 'uri', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token,
                ],
                'form_params' => $body,
            ]);
        } catch (ClientException $exception) {
            return $exception;
        }

Comment: _“if i do CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>http_build_query ($invoice), im getting blank response”_ - well if you lie to the server and pretend what http_build_query returns was JSON, you should probably not wonder about that too much …